# CentOS: How to force pip to install Django with latest Python 3.5

Tags: centos, python, pip, django

I'm running **CentOS**, and it has pre-installed Python 2.6.6. But I want to use Python 3.5, the latest version. So I have installed Python 3.5 on my server. It's working properly.

I just compile Python code like this:

Python 2.6:

```
python file.py
```

Python 3.5:

```
python3.5 file.py
```

These commands compile my code with the specific versions.

But I want to install **Django** with Python 3.5.1.  For example, if I use

```
pip install Django
```

I know it will install **Django**, but will it install Django with pre-installed Python 2.6 or the latest 3.5?

How can I **force** `pip` to install Django with Python 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is install Django in a `virtualenv` and not directly in your python installation (2.6 nor 3.5). Where you install `virtualenv` is not important (it probably goes into the 2.6 install):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

now create a 3.5 virtualenv by doing:

```
virtualenv -p $(which python3.5) /opt/django
```

(adapt the `/opt/django` to your needs), and then install within this 3.5 based virtualenv:

```
/opt/django/bin/pip install django
```

or first activate the virtualenv (in Bash) and then install

```
source /opt/django/bin/activate
pip install django
```